# Converting Ms -Sql db from Ascii to unicode

Tags: sql-server-2008, unicode, ascii, type-conversion

My SQL Server 2008 R2 database has string columns (`nvarchar`). And some of the old data is showing Ascii. I need to show it to the user in my site and I prefer to convert the data in the database to Unicode. Is there a quick way to do this? are there downsides that I should be aware of?

Examples to my issue:

- In the database, I see special chars instead of regulars chars. I have a name of a user which is supposed to be `Amédée`, and instead it shows `Am?d??`.
- In other cases I see `&#x22;` instead of Quotation mark (`"`), or the chars `&#` instead of the word "and".

Comment: What do you mean by "showing ASCII"? `NVARCHAR` columns are Unicode columns, so it's not clear where you are storing and/or seeing ASCII data. Can you provide more details about the data and what your precise problem is?

Comment: @Pondlife what I mean is for example I see special chars instead of regulars chars. I have a name of a user which suppose to be "Amédée" and instead it shows "Am?d??". In other cases I see "&#x22;" instead of Quotation mark(") or the chars "&#" instead of the word "and".

Comment: How are you inserting this data?

Comment: @Martin Smith  most of the data was inserted years ago and I just have it like that in my db.